# Adding classes to appending data

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `jQuery` and have some data that is coming in from a websocket. The data state is acknowledged,open and closed.

I am appending the data to a table

```
$(".incident-row").append(
        "<tr><td>"+incident.data.id+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+incident.data.state+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+incident.data.brief+"</td>"
        +'<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View details</button></td>'
        +"</tr>"
        );
```

I now want to use bootstrap to add a green,gray or red background class to the state depending on the state itself. The class is attaching correctly but is overwriting the existing class with the new class in the `DOM`

How can I rewrite this so each class stays on the effected row from the if statement?

```
if(incident.data.state === "OPEN"){
            $('.incident-row tr').addClass("table-danger");
         }
         else if(incident.data.state === "ACKNOWLEDGED"){
            $('.incident-row tr').addClass("table-active");
         }
         else if(incident.data.state === "CLOSED"){
            $('.incident-row tr').addClass("table-success");
         }
         else{
            return;
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector of $('.incident-row tr') is selecting all the incident rows.

You can use the **contains** selector.

```
$('.incident-row tr:contains("OPEN")').addClass("table-danger");
$('.incident-row tr:contains("ACKNOWLEDGED")').addClass("table-active");
$('.incident-row tr:contains("CLOSED")').addClass("table-success");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var className = "";
if (incident.data.state === "OPEN") {
    className = "table-danger";
} else if (incident.data.state === "ACKNOWLEDGED") {
    className = "table-active";
} else if (incident.data.state === "CLOSED") {
   className = "table-success";
} else {

}

$(".incident-row").append(
        "<tr class=\"" + className + "\"><td>"+incident.data.id+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+incident.data.state+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+incident.data.brief+"</td>"
        +'<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View details</button></td>'
        +"</tr>"
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution:

```
var stateClass = {"OPEN":"table-danger","ACKNOWLEDGED":"table-active","CLOSED":"table-success"};

$(".incident-row").append(
        "<tr class=\"" + stateClass[incident.data.state]+ "\"><td>"+incident.data.id+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+incident.data.state+"</td>"
        +"<td>"+incident.data.brief+"</td>"
        +'<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View details</button></td>'
        +"</tr>"
        );
```